# Python can't compare between values from the greatest common divisor

Tags: python, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to work through this hackerrank problem:

[image]

This is my attempt:

```
from fractions import gcd

def connectedCities(numCities, threshold, originCities, destinationCities):
    # Write your code here
    output = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(originCities)):
        if gcd(originCities[i], destinationCities[i]) > threshold:
            output.append(1)
        else:
            output.append(0)
    
    return output
```

But for an input of:

```
10
1
4
10
4
3
6
4
3
6
2
9
```

My output is:

```
Your Output (stdout)
0
1
0
1


Expected Output
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: how are you supposed to read that input?

Comment: @JakubDóka As a list

Comment: list of what? are these cities? then how big is trashold, how many clients we have?

Comment: In the attached image, there is an example to show the input shape

Comment: okey this will be tough one but doable

Comment: I'm waiting :) Thank you very much

Comment: as i expected it was pain and i dont even know if it is optimal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have absolutly no idea if this is good or not but it solves the problem all right.

```
from math import gcd

def exists(a, b, t):
    return gcd(a, b) > t

# find goes trough everithing it can
def find(paths, seen, start, end, true, path):
    for i in paths[start]:
        if i in seen or i == true:
            continue
        # creating shortcuts, it may backfire or help performance, it depends
        for j in path:
            paths[i].add(j)
        path.append(i)
        if i == end:
            return True
        seen.add(i)
        if find(paths, seen, i, end, true, path):
            return True
    return False


def solve(nc, t, sc, ec):
    ew = sc + ec

    # create lookup table
    paths = [None] * len(ew)
    for i in range(len(ew)):
        paths[i] = set()

    # fill it
    for i in range(len(ew)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(ew)):
            if exists(ew[i], ew[j], t):
                paths[i].add(j)
                paths[j].add(i)

    # traverse paths to find a values
    res = []
    seen = set()
    path = []
    for i in range(len(sc)):
        if exists(sc[i], ec[i], t) or find(paths, seen, i, i + len(sc), i, path):
            res.append(1)
        else:
            res.append(0)
        seen.clear()
        path.clear()
    return res
            
        

print(solve(10, 1, [4, 10, 4, 3, 6], [4, 3, 6, 2, 9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand how to read the input either. But I think I know why your code isn't spitting out the expected output. You are ignoring the transitive property.

Two cities are directly connected iff gcd of city numbers > threshold. However they can also be indirectly connected via other cities. Your code ignores that possibility.

```
Example:
numOfCities = 8
threshold = 1
2 is directly connected to 4, 6, 8 (gcd = 2)
6 is directly connected to 3 (gcd = 3)
therefore 2,4,8 can also reach 3
```

One Approach:
Cycle through all the city numbers and find directly connected cities (this will give you an adjacency dict)
Then use that adjacency dict (with a breadth or depth search) to see if the origin cities can reach destination cities.

Comment: Do you mind showing me a demo given the code that I havE?